# Android emulator - notification icon disappears instantly

Tags: android, android-emulator

### Problem

When using the android emulator coming with Android studio 2.2.3, a notification is displayed in the status bar just for a barely noticeable moment, then it disappears. When using a real device, the code works as expected - the icon remains visible in the status bar.

### The code

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(null)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Text")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .build();
nm.notify(12345, n);
```

### Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is because setPriority() by default is PRIORITY_DEFAULT = 0. 
If you setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX). Then the notification will be visible for couple of seconds before hiding.
As the priority increases significance of attention to notification increases.

Just wondering how is your device behaving otherwise.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the issue. If I set the priority to max, all it does is that instead of showing just the icon in the status bar, it also shows a "pop up" with the content of the notification. However the notification (including the icon) still disappears after a a second.

Comment: What is your emulator configuration? I will try to reproduce. I tested on Nexus6P emulator successfully.